# Chromed river is Not getting executable while running pipeline on Jenkins through docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, selenium-chromedriver, jenkins-pipeline

[Error What i facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZGhj.png)

Hello So I run the Jenkins through docker container after in Jenkins I integrated maven for run a java code while I m running on server i m able to run because I can make executable to chrome driver but how to do in Jenkins  to make it executable for Jenkins, there was test scenarios that run it needed chrome driver please any one help how to achieve this

Comment: Please paste the error text into your question, don't use screenshots of code or error messages.